# Particle collision animation Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to animate a particle collision animation in one axes object while simultaneously plotting some data in another axis object (using matplotlib.gridspec).
I set up a test environment with test data, simplifying the collision to just appearing circles in axes 1 (matplotlib.patches.Circle objects) and plotting a sine function in axes 2 (matplotlib.lines.Line2D object). 
The animation works for one axes at a time, but I can't run both axes animations simultaneously.

I think the problem is related to the return objects in the init() and animate(i) function. The "matplotlib.patches" and "matplotlib.lines" object have problems in combination with the animation, but I can't figure out why. 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

#%% setup test data
xy = (0.5, 0.5)
r = 0.02
i = np.arange(10,110)

#%% setup figure

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
gs = GridSpec(6,4, figure=fig, wspace=0, hspace=0) 

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4,0:4])

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[5:6,0:4])
ax1.set_xlim(0,100)
# assigning labels
circles = []
ln1, = ax1.plot([],[], 'r')

def init():
    ln1.set_data([],[])
    circles = []
    return circles, ln1

def animate(i):

    xy = (np.random.random(), np.random.random())

    circles.append(ax0.add_patch(Circle(xy,r)))
    x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    mask1 = x < i
    x1 = x[mask1]
    y1 = y[mask1]

    ln1.set_data(x1, y1)

    return circles, ln1

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames = i, blit=True, interval = 1)

plt.show()
```

That is the error message I  receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flofr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\flofr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 953, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\flofr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1741, in _init_draw
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flofr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\flofr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1269, in _handle_resize
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\flofr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1741, in _init_draw
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'
```

I tried to test if the return values are correct for init() and it seems to be the case.

**Input:**

```
def init():
    ln1.set_data([],[])
    circles = []
    circles.append(ax0.add_patch(Circle(xy,r)))

    return ln1, circles

a, b = init()
print(a)
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
Line2D(_line0)
[<matplotlib.patches.Circle object at 0x000001E7DE16F548>]
```

Here are the three states of the simulation. [Imgage one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaS0i.png) shows the layout, [image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqwe1.png) the axes 1 simulation (circles) and [image three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkKCh.png) the axes 2 simulation (sine).

Comment: You need to either set `blit=False`, or make sure to actually return a *sequence of artists*. Neither a sequence of one list and one artist, nor a sequence of one artist and one empty list will work.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, blit=False worked so far. However, for the second solution, is there a possibility to generate a _sequence of artists_ for this given example? I understand the idea but I'm not sure exactly how to implement this in the code.

Comment: Something like `return [line1, line2, circle1, circle2]`